# Debugging smart contract with source trace

Tags: contract-debugging

I am currently able to debug a tx with source trace in remix if I use my local geth node as rpc provider.

The problem is that keeping a local node in sync is time and resource consuming.

I am asking here if there is a way to use an external provider enabling debugging with source trace.

I have tried the combination remix + metamask (as injected web3) but, while it works for deploying/interacting with a contract, it does not allow debugging (one of the metamask devs confirmed me debugging is not supported)

So I tried etherscan that has a "remix debugger" option on the TX. It works but there is no source trace, when I explore the various fields it says "no source has been specified". How do I specify the source? The contract I am debugging has source verified on etherscan, I don't know what I could do more than that, debugging without source is impossible, you can't follow the contract logic...

So I am stuck without any other option that going back to the local node.

If anyone can suggest how to enable sources on etherscan or any rpc provider enabling debugging from my remix ide that would be greatly appreciated.